# Is there any way to get logs of SQL Database in Bluemix?

Tags: sql, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I have a Bluemix application which is using SQL Database.

I want to see logs of the database. Like what is the recent modification of data or tables?

Please advise.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is a _query language_ which is used by every relational DBMS. And which "logs" are you referring to? The "error log" where error and informational messages are written to by the DBMS? Or the "transaction log" where the DBMS writes crash-safe information? Different types of DBMS have different types of logs for transaction management (Oracle has REDO and UNDO, Postgres has WAL, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Bluemix but I am currently unaware of any relational database servers that offer a plaintext (that is, not recovery/rollback scoped) logging system.

Answer (score 0):

Users do not have access to the logs in SQL Database on Bluemix because it is a fully managed service. To be able to see the last modification time of a table, you may create a trigger to update the timestamp whenever there is a insert/update/delete operation on a table.

Comment: Can you please provide little more information how to create a trigger like that in Bluemix?